# Burn Code using Code Composer Studio

Tags: embedded, ti-ccstudio

I have been programming CC3200 using code composer studio.
I know how to run the debugger on my device and run the the code successfully. But I can't figure out how to burn the code on my device so I can use the device independently.

Comment: Briefly, you need to edit the linker command file to put your code sections in the flash memory. You may also need to do additional configuration (in code) or device specific stuff like moving interrupt tables (using linker command file).

Comment: Are you using the Launchpad?  Maybe [UniFlash](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CC31xx_%26_CC32xx_UniFlash) is what you need.

Comment: Yes, Launchpad. But I am not sure which is the type of file I have to flash onto my device using uniflash

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using UniFlash. There is a tutorial online that shows you how to do it.

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CC31xx_%26_CC32xx_UniFlash_Quick_Start_Guide

I believe you have to flash the program's .bin file. For example, the blinky application will have a file called blinky.bin, and this will be flashed onto the board via a selection on the UniFlash application. It is a url parameter than you can browse and modify in the UniFlash program. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[image]Use UniFlash, in release folder you will find a .bin file ( with the same name of your APP) and select ERASE and UPDATE and VERIFY, then connect cc3200 and go to System files ( /sys/mcuimg.bin ) , browse you .bin and after back to main screen in Uniflash and click Format and after Program, and VOILA

[image]